# How to Open a website at a certain point of time weekly

Tags: python, selenium

I Want to open a website  say https://stackoverflow.com through my browser automatically at 10 AM every Wednesday only and do some stuff(say clicking on a button).
How this can be done? I know a bit of python but not sure where to start.Do I need Selenium ?

Answer (score 1):

the best solution is to set your project on Jenkins, then use trigger automatically and add 'cron pattern' to schedule as you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the Linux system than have a look on crontab. please visit this site to understand more about it.
https://crontab.guru/examples.html

```
This runs every Wednesday 

00 19 * * 3 /home/user/run.py

# Use the hash sign to prefix a comment
    # +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
    # |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
    # |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
    # |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
    # |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
    # |  |  |  |  |
    # *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
    #------------------------------------
```

## If you are on window you can use the scheduler,

Make sure you logged on as an administrator or you have the same access as an administrator.
Start->Control Panel->System 
and Security->Administrative 
 Tools->Task Scheduler
Action->Create Basic Task-> 
 
Type a name and Click Next
Follow through the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. If you don't mind 1 thread running endlessly, you can just do a time check in your loop, and when its 10AM, run your scenario. This is not really a resource-friendly way nor is this the best way, but it will work.

Just create a loop which checks every minute if it is 10 AM on Wednesday and if true, run the tests.

Once again, not the best solution, but it is a solution.